# Cannot connect to the device with QSerialPort

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I develop Qt application in C++ under manjaro linux. The goal is to connect with a qC (Nucleo-L476RG Board) and receive data from accelerometer. App can find device on /dev/ttyACM0, but when i try to connect it fails with error "QSerialPort::DeviceNotFoundError". Checking errorString() gives "No such file or directory", but it still can find it in /dev.
I'm in the right group to read the file:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CG1yZ.png
I use Qt v.6.2.4, but have build the code with Qt v.5.15.3. I tried to run another person's app that does the same and works under ubuntu, but it didn't work.
Here is my code with the searching and connecting methods. Method addToLogs() just prints logs in textEdit.

```
void MainWindow::addToLogs(QString message)
{
    QString currDateTime = QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss");
    ui->textEditLogs->append(currDateTime + "\t" + message);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButtonSearch_clicked()
{
    ui->comboBoxDevices->clear();
    this->addToLogs("Szukam urządzeń...");

    QList<QSerialPortInfo> devices;
    devices = QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();
    if(devices.count() > 0)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<devices.count(); i++)
        {
            this->addToLogs(devices.at(i).portName());// + " " + devices.at(i).description());
            //ui->comboBoxDevices->addItem(devices.at(i).systemLocation());//portName());
            ui->comboBoxDevices->addItem(devices.at(i).portName());
        }
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButtonConnect_clicked()
{
    if(ui->comboBoxDevices->count() == 0)
    {
        this->addToLogs("Nie wykryto żadnych urządzeń!");
        return;
    }
    if(this->device->isOpen())
    {
        this->addToLogs("Port jest już otwarty!");
        return;
    }

    QString portName = ui->comboBoxDevices->currentText();

    //this->device->setPortName(portName);
    this->device->setPortName("/dev/ttyACM0");
    qDebug() << this->device->portName();
    if(device->open(QSerialPort::ReadWrite))
    {
        this->device->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
        this->device->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
        this->device->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
        this->device->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
        this->device->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

        this->addToLogs("Połączono z urządzeniem " + portName);
    }
    else
    {
        this->addToLogs("Otwarcie portu szeregowego się nie powiodło!");
        this->addToLogs(device->errorString());
        qDebug() << this->device->error();
    }
}
```

I will be thankful for help, cause i've benn sitting on it for last 2 or 3 weeks and nothing works.

Comment: For a start, isolate the problem into a [mcve]. Include that and the output it produces in the question. Compile it with warnings enabled but make sure it doesn't emit any. As a new user here, please also read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Thank You for Your help. I tried running app from terminal and there was an error, that there is 'libQt6Core.so.6' missing for Qt 6.3. I didn't know how to solve this, so I reinstalled whole QtCreator packet. Previously I installed QtCreator from flathub, but this time I downloaded installator from official Qt website. I installed it with Qt v6.3, and now it works, so I guess it was the problem with library in wrong version (it was in 6.2.4). Thank You for Your help one more time.

Comment: Also make sure you're not mixing Qt library versions. You're binary/executable should only link on one version of Qt. From the 'libQt6Core.so.6' missing for Qt 6.3 error message I assume you didn't specify all the library paths in the project file.

Comment: Can you open the device file and read from it using straight C I/O APIs? If you try the native operating system APIs they might reveal some useful information. In addition to that creating your own QObject derived class with appropriate signals and slots may also be an option.

Comment: Yes, the problem was mixing the lib versions. When I installed QtCreator it automatically downloaded different versions or i just have had some of them and they didn't get overwritten. I got all libs in the right versions and now everything is working.
And to clarify, yes, I could open the device in terminal and other C library based programm.